# PHP socket streaming gzipped data

Tags: php, gzip

I am receiving gzipped data via PHP sockets in a stream. The data is <strike>`RFC-1952`</strike> `RFC-1950` compliant.

```
while(($buffer = socket_read($this->socket, 1024))){
    $content .= $buffer;
}
```

The question is twofold.

1. Is it possible to use a wrapper to read the stream?
2. How do I detect end of gzipped file?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive there is a way to do this with:

```
fread();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't detect the end of gzip.

from rfc1952

> A gzip file consists of a series of "members" (compressed data
>         sets).  The format of each member is specified in the following
>         section.  The members simply appear one after another in the file,
>         **with no additional information before, between, or after them**.

You can merge  gzip files together and still be able to decode it because that will be still a valid gzip file. I think there is only starting signature

> ID1 (IDentification 1)
>            ID2 (IDentification 2)
>               These have the fixed values ID1 = 31 (0x1f, \037), ID2 = 139
>               (0x8b, \213), to identify the file as being in gzip format.

(0x1f 0x8b)

I think If the stream stops just decode the file.

Comment: the server is actually sending `RFC 1950` format. i think PHP's `gzencode()` with `FORCE_DEFLATE` does the same thing. i need to detect end of file

Answer (score 0):

For RFC 1950, zlib encoding, you use `gzuncompress()`.